# Delete partition and create two other partitions instead one?

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk, gparted, partition-table

i have structure of my hdd, like this:

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdb1          40       2048       2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2        4096  409602047  409597952  195.3G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3   409602048 5859477503 5449875456    2.6T Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb4  5859477504 5860524031    1046528    511M Linux swap
```

I want to delete `/dev/sdb3` and delete swap area `/dev/sdb4` and create two partitions with sizes `2.5T` and `1T` for `Linux filesystem`. How can i do this via linux utils, like fdisk and without using of live cd utilities, because this is a remote machine, and i don't have IPMI or VNC.

Comment: if sdb3 is your root(/) filesystem, You cannot reduce the while is mounted, if not you can delete the partition using parted recreate again

Comment: can you show us `mount`?

Comment: You should just be able to unmount `/dev/sdb3` and `/dev/sdb4` and then use `fdisk` to delete them and create new partitions.